# Trigger logic in class not updating field

Tags: apex, trigger, framework

I have a trigger that uses the BusinessHours.diff method to populate one field if two datetime fields are populated on a case. I want to have the logic in it's own class but for some reason i'm not getting it to update the field. I had an update DML statement in the class but the i was receiving the SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER error. So i took it out but now it won't do anything. Can someone point me in the right direction? I'm new, but i know this shouldn't be hard. Thank you

Trigger

```
trigger CaseTrigger on Case (before update) {
  BusinessHoursService.approvalHoursCalculation(Trigger.new);
}
```

Class

```
public class BusinessHoursService {

    public static void approvalHoursCalculation(List<Case> casesToCalculate) {

        casesToCalculate = [SELECT Id, SubmittedDate__c, ApprovedDate__c, ApprovalDuration__c
                            FROM Case
                            WHERE SubmittedDate__c != NULL AND ApprovedDate__c != NULL];

        string bhid = '01m39000000Cr71';

        if (casesToCalculate.size() > 0) {
            for(case c:casesToCalculate) {
                c.ApprovalDuration__c = BusinessHours.diff(bhid, c.SubmittedDate__c, c.ApprovedDate__c);
        }}        
    }   
}
```

Comment: Formatting tip: select the entire code block and press Ctrl-K or click the `{}` button.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are trying to using a **BEFORE** trigger, and in your trigger, you are trying to do a update **DML** call on records. In **BEFORE** triggers, any manipulation you do to the data happens before the records undergo their **DML** call, so you don't need to perform a DML call on the trigger records -- it's already gonna happen.

As per your requirement, you are almost doing correctly, just need little enhancement in your code.

```
//trigger handler for updating case approval duration field
     public class BusinessHoursService {


        public static void approvalHoursCalculation(List<Case> casesToCalculate) {
            if(CommonUtility.check){
                CommonUtility.check = false;

                Id businessHoursId = [select Id from BusinessHours where isdefault =true LIMIT 1].id;

                List<Case> updateCase= new List<Case>();

                for(case c :casesToCalculate) {
                    if(c.Date_Reported__c != NULL && c.DateofBooking__c != NULL){
                        Long difference= BusinessHours.diff(businessHoursId, c.DateofBooking__c, c.Date_Reported__c);
                        Long seconds = difference / 1000;
                        Long minutes = seconds / 60;
                        Long hours = minutes / 60;
                        Long dia = hours / 24;
                        c.Approval_Duration__c =dia; // here i am getting approval duration in days, if yu want you can calculate in hours also.
                        updateCase.add(c);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    //this class for avoiding trigger recursion
    public class CommonUtility{
            public static Boolean check = true;
    }
```

Please try this one it will work.

Comment: This answer almost covers it. The actual problem with the trigger as written by the poster, though, is not DML but the SOQL query they are running (which you've wisely removed).

There is no need for a static Boolean check here, and that particular style of recursion guard often leads to tricky-to-debug issues - it's not a good practice.

Comment: Awesome, thank you Kumari this worked. Like David Reed said I did not include the bool check. This was more of a proof of concept for me to play with than production code. I am curious though, why was the SOQL query causing it to not work? Thanks again

Comment: I added static Boolean check for recursion. You can skip that one if not required. See what was happening is we are updating record so for that we are getting record in the list( casesToCalculate). But after that again we are querying the record and storing in same list so it was overwritten the record list of list(casesToCalculate). So that was the issue i guess.

Answer (score 3):

As per your requirement, if `SubmittedDate__c` and `ApprovedDate__c` are populated then only you want to calculate the difference.

Since, you have written the code in `before update` trigger context and also querying those values from database, that's why it is not returning any values, because those data has not been saved to the database.

You can consider one of the following options:

Option 1: In the before update trigger context, take those values from the context variable rather than querying.

Option 2: Place those code in after update trigger context and then query those values and update the record.

Also, don't hard code BusinessHourId, rather query from the database, as it varies from org to org.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Santanu. I'm testing on a record that has the SubmittedDate and ApprovedDate values already, so I assume it'd be queryable at that point.